# Does Pervasive Database have a Scheduler?

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

Does the Pervasive Control Center (PCC) provide a scheduler? I want to run a sql statement on a schedule. Does Pervasive database offer any type of built-in scheduler, where I can add a statement and specify when it should recur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is no scheduler provided.  You could write a program that executes the query and schedule it using Task Scheduler.

There is a tool included in recent version of PSQL called `PVDDL.EXE` that can be used to execute a command file.  The command line is:

```
pvddl database commandfile
[-separator character] [-username username] [-password password] [-server servername] [-port number] [-stoponfail] [-log logfile]
```

Documentation for PVDDL.EXE is at http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/#page/uguide%2Fuguide.pvddl.htm

Comment: What command would I put into Task Scheduler, to pass it the file-location of the .sql file? Or, would I have to use some programming language to accomplish this instead?

Comment: @LonnieBest You could create the command in a BAT file, and then point the task at that file to execute it.  Might need to set the "run as highest privilege" (or something like that) option.